# Click twice to perform action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add confirmation text on a link when clicking, so the user just has to click once more on the same link/button to perform the action

But it fires at first click.. What can I do to get around this, or what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: it is for multiple links (any .button) on the page

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).text($(this).attr('title') + ' Sure? click again'); // adds confirm text to link

    if ($(this).text().lastIndexOf("click again", 0) != 0) {

      // NOW do the action

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you check the index of the text AFTER you set the text. The check would need to come before you set the text. But there are other ways to do it that do not involove relying of text. Text can change because some people use translation plug-ins built into the browser. Don't rely on text.

You can unbind the first click event and than add another one. This will just get rid of the check all together.

```
$(".button").on("click.confirm", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.text(btn.attr('title') + ' Sure? click again'); // adds confirm text to link
    btn.off("click.confirm");

    //Bind new click event that does next step...
    btn.on("click.next", nextStep);
});

function nextStep() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

If you want to do it with a boolean logic, you can use data() to store the state. In this case we will store a boolean true. When we set the message we set it to true, next click the if check will get the true and you can fire the next step.

```
$(".button").on("click.confirm", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var btn = $(this);
   if (btn.data("clicked")) { 
       nextStep();
   } else {
        btn.text(btn.attr('title') + ' Sure? click again'); // adds confirm text to link        
        btn.data("clicked",true);
    }
});
```

If you want to use classes instead of a data attribute it is simple also. Bonus is you can add a stylesheet rule to change the color.

```
$(".button").on("click.confirm", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var btn = $(this);
   if (btn.hasClass("clicked")) { 
       nextStep();
   } else {
        btn.text(btn.attr('title') + ' Sure? click again'); // adds confirm text to link        
        btn.addClass("clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: What is "confirm"? (click.confirm)

Comment: A namespace http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/ You do not need it, but it makes sure that when you remove the event, you remove that one and not all of the click events that can be added to the element.

Comment: @mowgli [jQuery: Event names and namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

Comment: Ok, I don't quite understand it ;) But where do I trigger my action then? After click, show confirm text, click again: action

Comment: Ok I will try. Will your example work for multiple links on a page?

Comment: Both will work for multiple since there are no global variables involved.

Comment: I showed you three options. Remove event handler, boolean logic with data, and boolean logic with a class.

Comment: Ok, the last added option looks good. Will try that too.. I was just chosing what looked simpler (no extra function) and easier to understand for me, and to incorporate in my code ;) Thank you anyway for the answer :)

Comment: Breaking code up into smaller chunks is normally good practice.

Comment: Yeah. I just first need to make it work in my code (which is a bit more complex than in the question code. that was just to isolate the issue itself), then tweak it. Why can't I accept two answers.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a read of what you're doing:

1. prevent default actions
2. Set text on the element to be the title with the text " Sure? click again" added.
3. Check to see if the text on the element has the text " Sure? click again".

You should see pretty clearly what's going on :)

My suggestion would be that you simply set a variable to determine whether or not something has been clicked.. it's a lot cleaner.

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;
$(".button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text($(this).attr('title') + ' Sure? click again'); // adds confirm text to link
    if (hasBeenClicked) {
      // NOW do the action
    } else {
        hasBeenClicked = true;
    }

});
```

Comment: @epascarello If there is, the OP should be able to figure out how to handle that. Such as setting the hasBeenClicked as a `.data()` item. I'm simply giving a very basic example.

Comment: hehe yes I could see it, but not quite understand how to get around it

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of my feelings on how you're doing this, unlike others I'm not going to tell you how to do it the "right" way or suggest something more complicated than your original code. You were just using `lastIndexOf()` wrong and were missing a little bit of logic.

Here's a fiddle showing the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/alistproducer2/y4SD3/

```
    $(".button").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).text().lastIndexOf("click again") == -1) {
            $(this).text($(this).attr('title') + ' Sure? click again'); // adds confirm text to link
        }else{             
             $(this).text('Worked');
        }

    });
```

Comment: But feel free to help me avoid any bad-practice ;)

Comment: I would use an attribute or class  to signal the state of the html element as opposed to relying on the text of it. Reason being, you may change the text at some point and that will break your functionality. Functionality should in no way be tied to the content of the html element.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did before (using the class attr).. Maybe should do that again. Just wanted to avoid adding/removing/checking class (and bubbling up?) and keep it simple thats all

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer keeps with your "keep it simple" philosophy. Anyways, please mark as answered.

Comment: text can change outside of your control. Translation plugins/services change text.

Comment: Sure, I'm fiddling with it, trying to use and check for class instead of text alone

Comment: Yeah, that's a better solution. So could I get the checkmark?

Comment: Thank you for the help :) Though, other answer has class change included, and some extra work and solutions put into it. Hope you understand. +1

Answer (score 0):

If it's a link, I would personally do it a different way - I would just assign the href attribute on the first click.

```
<a href="#" data-href="http://www.google.com" title="Whatever">Test</a>


$("[data-href]").click(function(e) {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('href'));
    $(this).text($(this).attr('title') + ' Sure? click again'); // adds confirm text to link
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FwZ2P/

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is indicate which links are actual double-click links which needs the confirmation and use appropriate `data-clicked="no"` attribute to store state of the click. Hence, this is easier to maintain than using global js variables.

Thus, this way it is still possible to bind several clicks using one method.

Check this **[js fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/S49QS/2/)**

Code also below with the comments:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="button" title="Double click link" data-clicked="no">Double click link</a> 
<a href="#" class="button" title="Double click link" data-clicked="no">Double click link</a>
<a href="#" class="button" title="Normal link">Normal link</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $btn = $(this),
        clicked = $btn.data("clicked");

    // if we have clicked a link which requires another click, 
    // and if we clicked it for a first time
    if (typeof clicked !== "undefined" && 
               clicked !== false &&
               clicked === "no"
       ) {
       $btn.text($btn.attr("title") + " Sure? click again");  

       // we mark that link has been clicked once
       $btn.data("clicked", "yes");

       // ..and return from this function, because we need another click from
       // the user to confirm the click action
       return false;
    }  

    // normal execution! - do whatever you want here..
    console.log("yay, activating click action!");

    // if this was data-clicked link, we reset it for next clicks
    if (typeof clicked !== "undefined" && clicked !== false) {
        $btn.text($btn.attr("title"));
        $btn.data("clicked", "no");
    }

});
```

Cheers.